# How to Fix: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to render an object from within a prop unto my component. I've been able to do this successfully with {artist.name}and {artist.genre), however. {artist.followers.total} fails with the error - cannot read property total of undefined

```js
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';
import './App.css';

class Profile extends Component {
    render() {
        // console.log('props from profile.jsx', this.props)
        // let artist = {name:'', followers: {href: '', total: ''}}
        let artist = this.state
        if (this.props.artist !== null) {
            artist = this.props.artist;


        };
        return ( <
            div >
            <
            div > {
                artist.name
            } /* works properly returns artist name name: "Kanye West" */ <
            /div> {
                artist.genres
            } /* works properly returns genres: (4) ["chicago rap", "hip hop", "pop rap", "rap"]*/

            <
            div > {
                artist.followers.total
            }
            /*causes run time error, I expect to see the total number of followers as received from the spotify API ollowers:
href: null
total: 10421208  Returns Cannot read property 'total' of undefined*/


            <
            /div>


            <
            /div>


        )



    }




}
export default Profile;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It simpily means `artist` is undefined or does not have `followers` in it.. you can console log it and check if the value is present

Comment: @panther , thanks for feedbak followers is included in the API response as an object . I can see this when I run console.log(artist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
artist.followers && artist.followers.total
```

Comment: Can you elaborate some more? Someone [flagged this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24298153) as low quality.

Comment: @JDN this worked !!! many thanks. Any idea why? I'm new to react and any additional info would go a long way

Comment: @IfeanyiIbekwe Because you checking `if (this.props.artist !== null)`.So, in the first time render of `Profile`, `artist.followers` don't have `total key`. And at the second time render, `artist.followers` will be have data by `this.props.artist`. `artist.followers.total` will be defined.

So, I checked if  `artist.followers defined` then get `artist.followers.total`

Comment: @jdn Got it !! makes sense, thank you again for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can also try **Optional chaining**, in order to make it shorter and simpler expression.

Example

```
let nestedProp = obj.first?.second;
```

By using the `?.` operator instead of just `.`, JavaScript knows to implicitly check to be sure `obj.first` is not `null` or `undefined` before attempting to access `obj.first.second`. If `obj.first` is `null` or `undefined`, the expression automatically short-circuits, returning `undefined`.

In your case:

```
let total = artist?.followers?.total
```